# Code 302 Found throw when forcing https codeigniter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I'm new at manipulating the `.htaccess`, I'm triying to force https on a webpage using `.htaccess` so if an user try to reach `http//localhost/myproject/` it will redirect to `https//localhost/myproject/` as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} 
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt) 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]  
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

The problem lies that when loading `http//localhost/myproject/`the browser do not redirect to `https//localhost/myproject/`, insted it return:

```
Found

The document has moved here.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

If I delete this line `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]`, the browser load the uri `https//localhost/myproject/`, but every other route like `https//localhost/myproject/about` won't load throwing error 404.

What is wrong in the .htaccess? How could it be solved?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `[L,R=301]` to your rule so the redirect takes place, and then your next rule will run on the next load.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```